# how to display entire record using php 5.3?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

in php 5.2 you were able to display an entire record easily like this:

```
$activeinfo = mssql_query("Select * FROM Associate where USR_ID = 1");
$USR_First = mssql_result($activeinfo,0,'USR_First');

echo $USR_First;
```

however in the newer versions 5.3+ you can only do one field at a time.

is there an easy way to echo an entire record (all fields) with 5.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using mssql_fetch_row() 
or mssql_fetch_array()
or even mssql_fetch_assoc()

for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-row.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-assoc.php